# How to debug javascript program

Tags: javascript, debugging

I can't find great way to debug javascript. I know firebug on firefox, but it's not best way I think. I want to put break point and trace program but I can't with it. 
Do you know good tool or how to trace the program.

Comment: You can put break point and trace in Firebug.

Comment: Firebug facilitates everything you've just listed. Under the script toolbar, you can add breakpoints and step through your program.

Also, inside your code, throwing things into console.log is extremely helpful.

Comment: You could have searched stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-do-you-debug-your-javascript-code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739221/what-is-a-good-javascript-debugging-tool and several others, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

[Venkman JavaScript Debugger](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/)

Answer (score 1):

Firebug Extension for Firefox (Yes, it also supports breakpoints) or the Webkit Inspector that's built into Safari and Chrome by default.

Both offer JavaScript debugging/profiling and a lot of other useful features.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/19/vs-2008-javascript-debugging.aspx

N.S.

Answer (score 0):

I find IE 8 Developer Tools (built into IE 8) and Visual Studio (2008, Express is free) are an excellent way to debug JavaScript -- at least in an environment compatible with the above tools :-)

Comment: considering, that IE8 is ... IE8 and that VS is rather heavy (ok, maybe not for most ppl out there), and also that IE + VS is basically solution for Win OS only (we don't know which one OP is working on) - this solution is not a good choice. I have IE8 and VS2010, but I can't live without firebug extension, when it comes to web dev (OP simply couldn't find the right tools)

Comment: Seriously, I'm not sure why I got a down-vote. Please read the full answer **"at least in an environment compatible with the above tools"** -- in which case, my answer is as good as any, *even if you are a Firefox/Firebug supporter*.

Comment: it's not mine down-vote. I know that your answer **is** a solution, but not for everyone (what probably is the reason behind this down-vote)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has some very nice developer tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the snippet **debugger;** in your javascript code that will allow you to debug on the browser console

```
function myFunction(){
        //Some stuff
        debugger;  //Debugging is automatically started from here
        //Some stuff
    }
    myFunction();
```