# jQuery not working on this page in any browser. I can't figure out why!

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging

http://www.fireviews.com/testing/tabs_and_toggles.html

The buttons with + signs are supposed to be drop-down toggles, and the mini-tabs below them should function as tabs. And at the bottom, the sample images should load (not just the spinning loader) and when clicked they should magnify the image, not go to another page. Also the magnifying glass in the top right should pop up a search bar when moused over. But none of this is working!

I think it may have something to do with the directory the js files are in (as I had to move them from their original location) but I thought I changed all the paths properly.

Can anyone help me identify where the errors/problems are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [prettyphoto.js](http://www.fireviews.com/design/js/prettyPhoto//design/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js) is actually a HTML file.

Comment: Aha! A typo in my path. I never would have caught that! Also, marooooon? What?

Comment: Ahhhh thank you so muck Pekka. It was just that one single typo. I fixed it and everything works beautifully! It's always something stupidly simple like that. 1000 internets for you, sir

Comment: Just saying that the page pekka linked is very intensely maroon.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use debugging tools that will reveal JavaScript errors to you. Just by opening your page in Firefox, I get:

```
Error: jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto'], a[rel^='lightbox']").prettyPhoto is not a function
Source File: http://www.fireviews.com/design/js/custom.js
Line: 239
```

And if I look at your JavaScript files, I see that http://www.fireviews.com/design/js/prettyPhoto//design/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js is not actually JavaScript. That's your problem.

See: [What is a good Javascript debugging tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739221/what-is-a-good-javascript-debugging-tool)

Comment: You're right artlung. Sorry, but this is my first foray into javascript (I'm using a web template for this project), so I don't have the right debugging tools yet, but I'll check out that link. Pekka pointed out this typo first so I'm going to have to give him the green check. But thanks for that link! It'll be handy.

Comment: My only mode is `--verbose`. :-)