# javascript related debugging tools or libraries?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

When you debug javascript related issues, any tools or libraries you can use to debug more easily to find the root cause? Any tool on Windows/Linux/Mac and for IE/Firefox are ok. I am just collecting a list of good tools so that I can use them to trouble shoot when I meet with any issues. :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I like and use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I would add: F12 pops up a similar tool on IE>7, and WebKit browsers have an "Inspect Element" entry in the contextual menu for the debug tool.

Comment: @Guillaume86, sure, it's just that those other tools are compared to FireBug, well ..., how can I put it most gently, ...

Comment: yeah I completely agree ;) but *sometimes* you only have the bug in a specific browser (IE hm hm) so it can be usefull

Comment: @Guillaume86, yeah, problem is that when there is an issue those other tools are not that helpful. For example the other day a colleague of mine (who is using IE for web development) was having an issue that I suspected was coming from a missing cookie. So I asked him, let's see what cookies are being sent to identify the problem. Obviously impossible to say. We needed to switch to more advanced tools like FireBug in order to solve the problem. And, yes, it was a missing cookie issue :-)

Comment: sure, Firebug Lite can help also

Answer (score 1):

[What is a good Javascript debugging tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739221/what-is-a-good-javascript-debugging-tool) here on SO

Answer (score 1):

1. Firebug (For Firefox and general JS debugging)
2. Developer Tools in IE8+ (comes built-in)
3. Web Inspector in WebKit like Chrome/Safari (comes built-in).

Other than that, you should be using Fiddler to keep track of performance/requests etc.

And finally JSFiddle.net for stand-alone testing.

Answer (score 1):

I use firebug most of the time with the following firebug plugins.

- [**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com)
- [**FireRainbow**](http://firerainbow.binaryage.com/), FireRainbow enables javascript syntax highlighting for Firebug. This is really cool. Saves a lot of time.
- [FirePHP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6149/),FirePHP enables you to log to your Firebug Console using a simple PHP method call.
- **[Widerbug](http://www.command-tab.com/2008/01/19/widerbug-widescreen-firebug/)**, can leverage wide screens for js debugging/development. Obsolete now as it is supported in Firebug 1.9 right out of the box.