# What are some good techniques at debugging javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

So I use JavaScript fairly regularly and I was wondering if there were any good tips or tricks in debugging javascript....Like for example I have a good one I use fairly regularly.

In my code i would do something like this

```
window.p = $(this);
```

and in the console I can do my filtering like this

```
window.p.next("li").find("a").val();
```

or whatever i need to do...but this makes it easy to debug a specific spot in the code and I know there has got to me many tips and tricks out there....thanks in advance

Also i looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739221/what-is-a-good-javascript-debugging-tool) and though its helpful i was looking more for techniques like my above ...

Comment: comm wiki please. There is no question here.

Comment: @red we don't do CW any more. If there's no question, there's no question that we close it as 'not a real question.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually set a breakpoint and look at the Scope Variables, or add my own watch expressions or hover over the variables and just step through the code.

Sometimes I find it useful to just log things using [`console.log()`](http://getfirebug.com/logging).

Other times, when things work, but they are too slow I use `console.profile()` and `console.profileEnd()`

A useful trick is the use of `$0`. If you have an element selected in the HTML pannel, you can reference it in the console as $0.

All techniques above work in Firefox+Firebug and Webkit based browsers (such as Chrome & Safari). Lately I prefer Chrome because it allows me to edit code inline (check this [tutorial by Paul Irish](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI))

For extra debugging help for jQuery I use [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at jQuery Lint first of all http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/. It will help you debug jQuery as you use it. Lint helps to report errors found in jQuery which are usually not obvious in Firebug or Developer Tools. You will find the usage examples at the website mentioned.

Also have a look at this page http://getfirebug.com/logging and start using `console` object to log and debug your code. You can use it both in Firefox with Firebug and Webkit (Chrome, Safari...) in Developer Tools.