# techniques of debugging large piece of javascript code

Tags: javascript, debugging

Recently, I have a chance to work on a project contains some large javascript files. I would say 4000-5000 lines per file. For example, there are 3 big files(custom plugin) build on top of each other. I got a debug task that needs to resolve(logically and it is not a js error). when I tried to debug and understand the logic under chrome dev tool such as step through or tracing where the variable came from and goes, I always get lost at some point because the files are so big. I thought maybe I need to sit down for 1 or 2 day to read through all the files and draw the logic on the paper, I guess that may be not a good solution. I wonder if there is any technique that I missed for debugging and tracing the variables or the logic. please share your experience with me. thanks

Comment: Check [what are good techniques...]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927249/what-are-some-good-techniques-at-debugging-javascript?rq=1) and some others Qs about debugging.

Comment: Logging messages to the console that let you know where in the code you are and what the variables look like are always a good starting point.

Comment: What kind of problem is it?  Can you provide some context, some approaches may be more efficient for certain problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when I look at something like that, I start by creating a test.  Try to test only the defect.  Take a working copy and try to reduce it down until you have isolated the problem.

Good luck!

Specifically, for advanced step-debugging, there is:

- using the call stack to inspect the local variables from the calling scope without having to step out of the function.
- using conditional breakpoints.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

If your JavaScript is making a lot of HTTP requests, it might also be useful to use the network tab to check the requests and responses are as expected.