# Anyone know of a good web debugging tool?

Tags: javascript, debugging, http

I need to trace the javascript and web traffic upon clicking on a button in a certain page (POSTing).

I'd like to go about the code step by step. Is there a way to do that? (Not debugging my code, I need to see what happens in the browser to any site)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good Javascript debugging tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739221/what-is-a-good-javascript-debugging-tool)

Comment: This is up for closure. In case it closes before you get all your answers, try asking Google that question and use StackOverflow's site. I think its been asked in multiple languages/platforms, so you should get a good return. https://www.google.com/search?q=web+debugging+tool+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to debug from the client side I find Google Chromes in built tools to be pretty handy.

You can find a nice introduction / overview of them [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview)

Comment: firebug is also interesting. It has a tool to select elements in the dom. Very useful.

Comment: @chepe263 If I get you right, Chrome can do the same. To my personal experience, the built-in chrome web developer tools are faster and more flexible than Firebug (I guess just because they are built-in).

Comment: yes, t's my favorite but i started to like firebug because i was working on a page with right click disabled

Comment: question: How can you hold execution once you pressed on SUBMIT, and go step by step on the events ?

Comment: answer's link is dead.

Comment: That link is no longer valid. Here's what it should be as of this comment being posted: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 3):

http://getfirebug.com/

Firebug integrates with Firefox to put a wealth of web development tools at your fingertips while you browse. You can edit, debug, and monitor CSS, HTML, and JavaScript live in any web page.

Comment: question: How can you hold execution once you pressed on SUBMIT, and go step by step on the events ?

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler is wonderful: http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/.  It acts as a proxy, allowing you to inspect every step of the request/response cycle.

Comment: question: How can you hold execution once you pressed on SUBMIT, and go step by step on the events ?

Comment: @Ted - I'm not sure if I understand your question. Fiddler records and displays each event as it occurs.

Comment: Thanks I just found that it is possible to halt on all requests. It is very cool! But sometimes when I refresh it doesn't monitor the requests... any idea why ?

Comment: @Ted - Is your page using AJAX or a similar technology? That won't send a new request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, try [HTTP Debugger](http://www.httpdebugger.com/) as well.