# jQuery colorbox and onOpen callback event

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using jQuery colorbox and load HTML into an iframe. All is working okay. While
the iframe loads, I wanted to display a message along the lines of "stand by the page is loading"

I tried using the callback interface....if I use the traditional example of sending an alert
prior to the load/open event, it works okay. If I try to use document.write to display a message,
I see the message but the iframe doesn't load.

```
            //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
            $(".iframe").colorbox({
                                            iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%",
                                           onOpen:function(){document.write("fff"); }

                                });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `document.write()` after the page has loaded. If you do, it will completely stop out the document's contents. In fact, [just don't use `document.write()` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

If you need something better than `alert()` for testing & debugging **(you do)** use [`console.log()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739221/what-is-a-good-javascript-debugging-tool).