# Array push is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Why is array push  not working in the following
code? Can someone find the mistake please ?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
words=new Array("limit","lines","finish")
words.push("complete","In","Out")
var jwords=words.join(;)
document.write(jwords)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The console shows: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`. Stackoverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: @FelixKling:Where did you get this error?

Comment: As I said, in the console. Chrome has built in developer tools and so does Firefox. You can also use Firebug for Firefox and there should be some extensions for IE too.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for the help.I am a beginner in web technology.

Comment: Also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739221/what-is-a-good-javascript-debugging-tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
words.join(;)
```

should be:

```
words.join(";");
```

This is in fact a syntax error and can be caught by your browser (<kbd>F12</kbd>).

Some tips:

1. Create variable names with the keyword `var`. Your `words` variable was not created with `var`.
2. Don't use the `Array` constructor. Use the array literal syntax `[]`. That's means change the first line to:

   ```
   var words = [ 'limit', 'lines', 'finish' ];
   ```
3. Use `console.log` instead of `document.write`. You can view the result in your browser by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd>. `document.write` causes problems when used in certain situations so it's best to avoid it.

Comment: What do you suggest for learning JavaScript?

Comment: @ManojitGhosh [Maybe you should get a good resource.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript)

Comment: You could read "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" by David Flanagan. And "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the `;` parameter in this line

> var jwords=words.join(';')