# Calculate and pass the sum of 2 variables values in a third

Tags: jquery, variables

I would like to calculate the width of 2 divs and pass the sum in a third, all values stocked in variables.

HTML:

```
<div id="value-a"></div>
<div id="value-b"></div>

<div id="value-c"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
var value_a = $('#value-a').css('width');
var value_b = $('#value-b').css('width');
var value_c = (value_a + value_b);
$('#value-c').css('width', value_c);
```

It look like i'm wrong with the syntax to make the operation...

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should also learn [__Debugging JavaScript__](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Also see [What is a good Javascript debugging tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739221/what-is-a-good-javascript-debugging-tool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.width()`:

```
var value_a = $('#value-a').width();
var value_b = $('#value-b').width();
var value_c = (value_a + value_b);
$('#value-c').width(value_c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Javascript Solution also

```
var value_a = document.getElementById("value-a").offsetWidth
var value_b = document.getElementById("value-b").offsetWidth
var value_c = (value_a + value_b);
document.getElementById("value-c").style.width=value_c+'px';
alert(value_c )
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS4L7/184/)

Comment: interesting solution, thanks, is it possible for example to calculate the "margin left" instead the "width" with this solution?

Comment: use `document.getElementById("value-a").style.marginLeft`

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
$('#value-c').width($('#value-a').width() + $('#value-b').width());
```